# Binding DropDownList into MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Reading from here: [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Action `SelectCategory` has been created inside controller -

```
 public ActionResult SelectCategory() {

     List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();    
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0"});    
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });    
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", Selected = true });    

     ViewBag.MovieType = items;

     return View();    
 }
```

I am not able to understand binding of Data in following line.

```
@Html.DropDownList("MovieType")
```

While binding data in similar way,

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdList");
```

I obtain following error-

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'IdList'.

**Controller Action**:

```
public ActionResult SelectId()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MyId1", Value = "MyId1", Selected=true });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MyId2", Value = "MyId2" });

        ViewBag.IdList = items;
        return View();
    }
```

What am I missing ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. May be you should try @Html.DropDownList(ViewBag.IdList);

Comment: Html.DropDownList has 8 (eight) overloads which allow you to specify everything including the list you want to show in options. Please go through the documentation of Html.DropDownList here

Comment: try out this Html.DropDownList("anyname",ViewBag.IdList) - this constructor accepts two params - name and the list you want to display

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have set `ViewBag.MovieType` => when you use `@Html.DropDownList("MovieType")` the dropdown will use this value. When you write `@Html.DropDownList("IdList")`, the helper doesn't find a corresponding `IdList` property in ViewBag and throws an error because it doesn't know from where to bind the data.

Alternatively if you want to change the name of the dropdown you could use the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedMovieType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MovieType)
```

and your POST action will have a `SelectedMovieType` parameter to retrieve the selected value.

But I would avoid ViewBag. Defining a view model is better:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedMovieType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MovieTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult SelectId()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MyId1", Value = "MyId1", Selected=true });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "MyId2", Value = "MyId2" });

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        MovieTypes = items    
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedMovieType, Model.MovieTypes)
```

Answer (score 4):

while binding you list to DropDown you need to type cast it to IEnumerable as you use @Html.DropDown control which is not **strongly type with Model**

In View

```
@Html.DropDownList("MovieType",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MovieType)
```

and for another way if you bind IdList then

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdList",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IdList)
```

Comment: Hi Shivkumar, Above code throws error: `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'IdList'.` Any suggestion ?

Comment: @autrevo can you please  show me some snaps of error because i am not able to reproduce it here

Answer (score 1):

A painless way for data binding to bind data to the model: **Do not use the razor for Dropdown.** Bind it manually, get it with FormCollection object.

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Sorun sorun,FormCollection fc)
    {
        //Define independently as form collection

        sorun.GonderilecekBirim = fc["GonderilecekBirim"];
        sorun.IlkSorulmaTarihi = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Soruns.Add(sorun);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(sorun);
    }
```

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.GonderilecekBirim, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <!-- Define as raw html -->
            <select id="GonderilecekBirim" name="GonderilecekBirim">
                <option value="4">Satın Alma</option>
                <option value="5">Muhasebe</option>
            </select>

            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GonderilecekBirim, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
```