# Dropdown list in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I am a newer fresher in ASP.Net MVC.

I want to create a drop down list control. That is my member class.

```
Public Class Member

    Public Property MemberID As Integer
    Public Property MemberName As String

End Class
```

This is my controller class.

```
Function Login() As ActionResult
    Dim Members As List(Of Member) = HttpContext.Application("Members")

    ViewData("Members") = New SelectList(Members)

    Return View()
End Function
```

In my view class.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Members")
```

But the drop down shows members...members...members. How can I fix it? Thanks all.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985088/binding-dropdownlist-into-mvc-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller action you could specify the names of the properties on your model to be used as value and text for the dropdown:

```
ViewData("Members") = New SelectList(Members, "MemberID", "MemberName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your code

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedMember", 
    new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable) ViewData["Members"], "MemberId", "MemberName"))
```