# ViewModel vs. InputModel in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

As I found on [10 Good practices for asp.net mvc webapplications](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1405071) it is a good practice to split mvc models in ViewModel (Models representing the view) and InputModels (Representing data entered by user).

The ViewModel gets a property of Type InputModel. The InputModel carries the data that can be edited by the user.

```
public class EmployeeInputModel{

     public string Name {get;set;}
     public Id? DepartmentId{get;set;}

}


public class EmployeeCreateViewModel{
      public IList<Department> Departments{get;set;}
      public EmployeeInputModel EmployeeModel{ get;set;}
}
```

The Controller-methods look like:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller{

     public ActionResult Create(){
          var viewModel = new EmployeeCreateViewModel(DepartmentService.GetAll(), new EmployeeInputModel());
          return View(viewModel);
     }

     public ActionResult Create(EmployeeInputModel createModel){
          try{
               EmployeeService.Create(...);
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
          } catch (Exception ex){
               var viewModel = new EmployeeCreateViewModel(DepartmentService.GetAll(), createModel);
               return View(viewModel)
          }

     }
}
```

The View looks like:

```
  @model EmployeeCreateViewModel

  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmployeeModel)
```

The Editor Partial is just like:

```
  @model EmployeeInputModel

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.DropDownFor(m => m.Department, ???)
```

This worked great for me, unless I came to the point of DropDownLists (in the sample see departments). Because the EditorTemplate doesnt know the ViewModel but just the InputModel.

I dont want to put the department list into the input model, because it is not the supposed place to be for this list (I would have to bind them). It has to be in the viewmodel. The properties of the input model should also not be in the ViewModel.

Does someone have any idea how to achieve a separation of viewmodel and input model in one view?

Comment: Even though, I agree with most parts of the article, I can not see the great benefit from splitting a "input model" from the view model. The view model is supopsed to be "the view" on the data the user is editing, so there is no need to have a seperate input model and in your case it also over complicates things

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a model abstraction of your departments. Something like this:

```
public class EmployeeInputModel{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public List<DepartmentInputModel> Departments{get;set;}
}

public class DepartmentInputModel{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
}
```

Then you can display just the name of the department in the drop down list. The value will then be the id of the department.

You can have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985088/binding-dropdownlist-into-mvc-view) for a example.

Comment: This would mean I had to bind all the departments with the input model. That is from my point of view wrong. The input model should just bind the id of the selected department.

Comment: Oh maybe I missunderstood the question then. You just want to place the selected department in the viewmodel and get it back without the user editing it?

Comment: The Id of the selected department is set via modelbinding according to the selected department in the dropdown. the selectable departments should be available just in the viewmodel, not in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewBag yo pass the list of departments to your partial.
Or use a partial view that accepts the view model as its model

Comment: ViewBag is no option because it is not refactoring safe and you can read it almost everywhere that ViewBag should be avoided.