# Drop down list with select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my select list from model.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ServiceCycleList
{
    get
    {
        var Item = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Yearly", Value = "12" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Quarterly", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Monthly", Value = "1" }
        };
        return Item;
    }
}
```

I want to Create one dropdown list for this select list. How Can I to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding DropDownList into MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985088/binding-dropdownlist-into-mvc-view)

Answer (score 0):

If it is available in the View with the model, you could create the `DropDownList` like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourModelProperty, new SelectList(Model.ServiceCycleList, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select...")
```

Comment: It gives null reference exception.

Comment: @NiteeshJoshi I presuming the null reference exception would be on the `Model.ServiceCycleList`. Set that in the controller then do this

Comment: My code above is just an example based on the info you have provided. You'll need to mould that into your specific case. I don't have 100% of the info to give you a 100% solution.

Comment: I have taken foreign key of this service list's class. And my model in view is MonthlyTransactions in that model I have foreign key of ItemService which contains this ServiceCycleList. So, if I write like  `@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ItemServiceMasters.ServiceCycle, Model.ItemServiceMasters.ServiceCycleList, "Select Frequency", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", })`  then it gives error for null reference and `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, your action method is returning a view without a model, and thus the error you get is the model is null.

```
public ActionResult Index(..)
{
   .
   .

   return View(); // missing model reference
}
```