# How to bind model value to static dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
           @model OnlineExam.Web.Models.QuestionBank               
             <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <lable>Is Active</lable><br /><br />
                    <select name="IsActive" id="IsActive">
                        <option value="true">Yes</option>
                        <option value="false">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <div>
                <div>
```

Here i have normal dropdown but i have model value @Model.IsActive in this i will get true or false. I need to bind my model value in dropdown

```
public ActionResult EditQuestionBank(string QBID)
                {
                    ViewBag.Sections = GetSections();
                    ViewBag.DifficultyLevel = DifficultyLevel();
                    questions = ViewQuestionDetails(QBID);
                    return View(questions);
                }
```

This is my controller code

Comment: There should be a lot of guides around on how to bind MVC model to a dropdown list. you could give this one a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985088/binding-dropdownlist-into-mvc-view

Comment: but here i have select dropdown how can i modify

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what part of the binding process you're talking about. In theory if the "name" of the select matches the property name in your model then it should already bind when you submit the form, and populate the model on the server. But if you want it to bind to the existing value in your model when displaying the page then you must either a) make it a non-static dropdown using `HTML.DropdownListFor`, or b) write some simple Razor code to check the current model value and inject a `selected` attribute to the correct `<option>` in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HTML drop-down, maybe it helps but try to use '@Html.DropDownList'

```
             @model OnlineExam.Web.Models.QuestionBank               
             <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <lable>Is Active</lable><br /><br />
                    <select name="IsActive" id="IsActive">
                        <option value="true" @(Model.IsActive ? "selected" : "")>Yes</option>
                        <option value="false" @(Model.IsActive==false ? "selected" : "")>No</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

> Using Jquery

```
$("#IsActive").val('@Model.IsActive');
```

Comment: in options it is not taking model  and it is coming in red colour

Comment: Make sure your `Model` class has `IsActive` filed please check?

Comment: binding is not working properly i.e, i have value false in model.IsActive  then it is binding with "Yes" but actually its need to bind with "No"

Comment: If possible, Please share your controller code also.

Comment: i have added my controller code in question can you please check once

Comment: Ok, thank for this but first you need to check in your view page your model value come or not. Using `@Html.Raw(Model.IsActive)`

Comment: Model.IsActive value is coming to my view